# Wix Toolset RemoveFolderEx Element (Util Extension)

Tags: c#, xaml, wix, windows-installer

I have installer for my C# application , Install and uninstall works fine when there are no additional files/logs created while running utility .

But when logs are generated , uninstall doesnot remove the directory and the logs . 
I tried using RemoveFolderEx Element (Util Extension) , but I do not have component Id for the output folder in which logs are saved as it is created on runtime.

How can I remove output folder so that uninstall goes clean, without leaving files and folders

Comment: Will you always know the name of the log file in question? And where do you log? I assume you create a sub folder and log there? If so you need a CreateFolder entry to create that logging folder on install and a RemoveFile entry to delete the log file on uninstall. For the record logging in your installation folder is not according to Microsoft logo requirements.

Comment: Yes , I know the names of the log files and also create a sub folder in installation folder and log the files there.

Comment: also to add , I do not see any CreateFolder entry to create that logging folder on install but still I can see output folder being created and files are logged in the folder

Answer (score 0):

***This is a little rushed. I will check back if it makes sense to you.***

You should be able to use the standard and built-in [RemoveFile feature](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html) in MSI to remove log files - if you know the name of the files in question. Then you can add a **CreateFolder** entry to your installer which creates the logging directory in question and then use that directory property in your RemoveFile entry:

[Sample from github](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/7c8457fa3802858add8981b92996e19574e762da/src/Setup/CoreMsi/Doc.wxs):

```
<Component>
  <File Source="WiX.chm" />
  <Shortcut Id="WixChmShortcut" Directory="ShortcutFolder" Name="WiX Documentation" 
            Icon="WixSetupIcons.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />

  <RemoveFile Id="RemoveWixChw" Name="WiX.chw" On="uninstall" />
</Component>
```

[CreateFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368053(v=vs.85).aspx) is a WiX element that you insert to indicate that an empty folder should be created as part of your installation:

```
   <Directory Id="Mydir" Name="My Directory">
      <Component Feature="MyFeature" >
        <CreateFolder />
        <File Id="NOTEPAD.EXE" Source="$(var.MyReleasePath)\Main Folder\NOTEPAD.EXE" />
      </Component>
   </Directory>
```

---

***Some further thoughts***:

- I would not do logging in the installation folder - this folder is supposed to be read-only.
- I would log elsewhere, somewhere in the UserProfile perhaps, or even the temp folder (and let it be cleaned by whatever mechanism the end users have for that).
- I would also consider logging to the system's event log instead of to a file, if possible.